# Novell Identity Manager (NIM) 3.6: How to make an image part of the resources for HTML reports?

Tags: image, html, novell, identity-management

This question might not belong here, and since this is related to an identity management product, I thought I could ask nonetheless.

I'm currently working to list all of the user identities in Designer for Identity Manager, by Novell.

I used the User Application connector and built the required queries. I also created a Provisioning and Request Definition with the necessary fields.

I can populate an HTML table with the results of the selected query, and get the user information from the Vault. Aside, I could use the organization's logo on the top-left-hand corner, the project name on the top-right with the report title just below on the right-hand side.

My concern is to set the organization's logo on the report.

> **Question**

1. How can I define this image logo as an image resource into NIM so that I can use it in my HTML  identity report?

**EDIT #1**

I know that NIM uses Tomcat 5 as its Web server or the like, I don't know much about it, really. Nevertheless, should it suffice to move the image to its "Website" directory so that I can give the relative "web" path to the image as part of the resources for the "website" NIM uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered on [StackoverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865340/novell-identity-manager-nim-3-6-how-to-make-an-image-part-of-the-resources-for).

Comment: Yes, and thanks for your great answer! I'm anxious to try the solution!